# Does an Oath of Vengeance Paladin have to pick a particular sworn foe?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

Of the Oath of Vengeance paladin's four tenets in the PHB, two mention the phrase "sworn foe/enemy":

- "Faced with a choice of fighting my sworn foes or combating a lesser evil, I choose the greater evil."
- "Ordinary foes might win my mercy, but my sworn enemies do not."

Does that imply that a player making a vengeance paladin has to pick a "sworn foe" in particular, like a kind of enemy (e.g., goblins or dragons) or is it any enemy that you are facing in battle right now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nowhere in the Oath of Vengeance (or any Oath, actually) does the character *have to* pick a sworn foe. Mechanically, there is no effect whatsoever. You can contrast this to the Ranger's *Favored Enemy* feature, which clearly states that the Ranger has to choose enemies.

However, for role-playing reasons, a character might swear an oath against an enemy (there is no restriction, one of my players even swore an oath of vengeance against Demogorgon) and base some in-game decisions on the oath. It's good role-play, and *Inspiration*-worthy.

Comment: My favorite Oath. I built my paladin Oath and tenets into his story. He became a Paladin and took an Oath to no god or goddess..but to himself; swearing an oath of vengeance against the undead that desecrated his troops and city; strictly so he could hunt them down. It was consistently inspiration worthy.